# Adding class active on jQuery

Tags: jquery

How is the setting for class active when menu is clicked with jQuery?

> auth/index" title="Dashboard"> Dashboard

```
  <!-- MASTER -->
  <li class="">
     <a href="#" title="Master"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-desktop txt-color-blue"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent txt-color-blue">Master</span></a>
     <ul>
        <li class="">
           <a href="" title="Master"><i class="fa fa-check-square txt-color-blue"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">SubMaster1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
           <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>auth/index" title="Master"><i class="fa fa-check-square txt-color-blue"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">SubMaster2</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
           <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>auth/index" title="Master"><i class="fa fa-check-square txt-color-blue"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">SubMaster3</span></a>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and has no code attempt. Please elaborate your problem as well as provide your code effort too.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can add active class to element with [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function. So, for your scenario code might look like as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $("a[href=" + window.location.href + "]").parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Here I have checked the url with `href` attribute of `a` tag.

This is the Basic concept, you can modify the above code as per your requirement.

Comment: I don't think in OP's case it will work because the page will get refreshed after the click.

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you for your suggestion. I have update my answer, I hope this will work fine.

Comment: OP needs to decide it. I am afraid that he will update very soon, as he posted question and gone for sleep :):)